# Json number format

Tags: android, json

I have the following code :

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(new String(cod_bare));
    for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();  i++) 
        {
            cod_in_loop=jsonArray.getString(i);
            .....
        }
```

code_bare = [085845,0547561....]

The problem is that cod_in_loop show the number without de 0 => 085845 it ends in cod_in_loop just 85845. I need the full number "085845"

What to do ?

Comment: cod_in_loop is declared as String. And it ends like this : 85845.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the JSON, not the code. If your JSON is really

```
[085845,0547561....]
```

then it's **invalid**; in [JSON](http://json.org/), you're not allowed to start a number with a `0` unless the `0` is immediately followed by a `.` (e.g., `0.1`), as we can see from the handy diagram from http://json.org:

[image]

...and from this text in [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-6):

> The representation of numbers is similar to that used in most
> programming languages.  A number is represented in base 10 using
> decimal digits.  It contains an integer component that may be
> prefixed with an optional minus sign, which may be followed by a
> fraction part and/or an exponent part.  **Leading zeros are not
> allowed.**

*(my emphasis)*

So the fix here is to correct the JSON. If you want to preserve the leading zero, then that pretty much means that the thing you're dealing with isn't a number, it's a series of digits — e.g., a string, so:

```
["085845","0547561"....]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 I need the full number "085845"
```

I can't understand why you are using Json. If `code_bar` is a `String` I think that you must `split the string`

```
//java code
String code_bar = "[1,2,3,4,5,6"];
        String[] arrayNumbers = code_bar .split(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayNumbers .length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arrayNumbers [i]);
        }
```

**You must add something for delete `"["` and `"]"`

Finally if you need use json you must add `{` and `}` in `code_bar`:

```
//c# code:
var array = JArray.Parse(code_bar.Trim('{', '}'));
List<String> listNumbers = array.ToObject<List<String>>();
```

Comment: *"Finally if you need use json you must add { and } in code_bar"* No, it's perfectly valid for an array to be the top-level item in a JSON document.

Comment: ah ok, sorry for that.